# Custom photo editor's View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to override Apple's editor view?
(I mean the view that you see when you enable `allowsEditing` in `UIImagePickerController` )

I would like to add some buttons to it from my app, or do I need to create my own VC if I want to intercept the picked photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to modify Apple's imagePicker UI, but they do provide code to develop your own:

[Apple's sample MyImagePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html)